# convert List<HashMap<String,String>> to list<map<String,String>> java

Tags: java, android

I have a `List<HashMap<String,String>>` and I want to convert it to `List<Map<String,String>>` in java. Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Those seem to be compatible enough already in most cases. Where exactly do you need to do that? Please show some code.

Comment: what promotes you to think so? IMHO, almost everything you can achieve that with a HashMap that you can wish to do with a Map.

Comment: It is something like this. I have another method which returns List<HashMap<String,String>>. And after calling that I need to assign that in some other global variable which is List<Map<String,String>>. Unfortunately I can't change the return type of that method or type of that public variable. That's why I need this conversion.

Comment: Just create a new list, and add each element from the old one into the new one. (It's unsafe to try to cast the current list, because then someone could add a `TreeMap<String,String>` to it -- and now anyone who has the original reference will have a `List<HashMap<...>>` that actually contains a `TreeMap<...>`, which will cause a class cast exception that's hard to track down.)

Comment: @yshavit: On the other hand, now you have a copy of the list, and any changes to the copy (as far as list membership is concerned) won't reflect back to the original. (And if you say that this is not a concern, then we could just have cast it).

Comment: @Thilo Absolutely. If the list is mutable, you can't have both; either the list is a copy and changes aren't reflected, or changes are reflected but you open yourself up to class cast exceptions. (I suppose you could also have a list that only allows removal, not addition or setting, but I don't know of any such implementation off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing but you have to create a new list of Map. Then iterate the list of HashMap and simply add each object to the list of Map. Like the following:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMapList = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("Ussain", "Bolt");
hashMapList.add(hashMap);

List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
for (HashMap<String, String> map : hashMapList) {
    mapList.add(map);
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier that you thought.

First, create a `List<Map<String, String>>`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = new List<>();
```

Then, just loop through your original list and add each item to the new list:

```
// This for loop basically says "for each item in yourOriginalList..."
// if you didn't know
for (HashMap<String, String> item : yourOriginalList) {
    result.add(item);
}
```

"Why can I add a `HashMap` to a list of `Map`s?" you might ask.

That's because of *polymorphism*. Since `Map` is an interface and `HashMap` implements `Map`, wherever you need a `Map`, you can give it a `HashMap`, as long as the generic type arguments are the same.

Comment: Also, seems excessive to have to copy the list at all. Cannot it be cast (even though it's unsafe in general)?

Comment: I tested casting and the copy constructor with the Java7 compiler and both didn't compile. Maybe it can be compiled in Java 8? @Thilo

Comment: I think you have to use the unsafe cast (`list = (List) originalList`). And yes, there will be a warning about it.

Comment: Hmm. I thought copy-constructor would have worked. How about `addAll(originalList)` ?